# Can`t install perl module Crypt::TEA

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module, xs, perl5.18

When I try to install Crypt::TEA module to perl 5.18 on Windows 7, displayed error:

> TEA.xs: In function 'XS_Crypt__TEA_crypt':
>       TEA.xs:58:9: error: invalid use of void expression

Comment: I get the same error.  SvUPGRADE does not return a value and can't be used how it's being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is [this line](https://metacpan.org/source/AMS/Crypt-TEA-1.25/TEA.xs#L58):

```
    if (SvREADONLY(output) || !SvUPGRADE(output, SVt_PV))
        croak("cannot use output as lvalue");
```

SvUPGRADE() is a macro with two void operations, it does not return a value.  It will croak if it fails.  Change it to this:

```
    if (!SvREADONLY(output)) 
        SvUPGRADE(output, SVt_PV);
```